# Merging Two Binary Search Trees

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree

What time in terms of Big O will it take to merge two BST's in One? 
Each having no of nodes n and height O(log n) with no common element.

Resultant should be also a BST

Comment: What is the algorithm?

Comment: There isn't any algorithm given its a general question. But I guess it is done by Search function of BST and Insert.

Comment: The naive way would be to iterate the smaller tree (n) and insert each node into the bigger one (m). Resulting in O(n*log(m+n)) ...perhaps there is a fancy algortihm which can do that it a "hand in hand" iteration and result in O(n+m) ...at least that would be the lowest attainable bound. Whether there is an algo achieving it is another question.

Comment: Take a look at [How to merge two BST's efficiently?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1008513/3235496)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008513/how-to-merge-two-bsts-efficiently) @manlio pointed out is an exact duplicate. Basically, yes, the algorithm can improved to O(n+m); the approach is to flatten the trees to sorted lists, merge them, and recreate a BST. [This page](http://dzmitryhuba.blogspot.com/2011/03/merge-binary-search-trees-in-place.html) also has some example code that may be of interest as well.